# "Table has no rows" Error in Google Charts Histogram

Tags: google-visualization, histogram

I am working with Google Histogram chart. It working fine with some data sets but not for other data sets. And it raise an error "Table has no rows" even my input is correct.
Here i am reading a csv file column wise and pass to visualization page.

for eg:  I am reading 2 csv column here and passing to visualization page. Here my input to Google histogram is

```
var inputdata1 = [["val","d"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"]];
```

and this working fine and gives histogram for me.

while I am passing other 2 columns.Here my input to Google histogram is

```
var inputdata2 =  [["val","b"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","5"],["val","1"],["val","12"],["val","7"],["val","11"],["val","1"],["val","7"],["val","6"],["val","16"],["val","11"],["val","21"],["val","12"],["val","1"],["val","22"],["val","16"],["val","1"],["val","21"],["val","11"],["val","6"],["val","11"],["val","15"],["val","12"],["val","12"]];
```

while executing this, it raise an error that "Table has no rows" . Please check my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hkg8wsmm/3/).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact neither `inputdata1` nor `inputdata2` contain JSON data that are supported by *histogram chart*.

According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/histogram) the following formats are supported:

> **Data Format**
>
> There are two ways to populate a histogram datatable. When there's
>   only one series:
>
> ```
>  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>     ['Name', 'Number'],
>     ['Name 1', number1],
>     ['Name 2', number2],
>     ['Name 3', number3],
>     ...
>   ]);
> ```
>
> ...and when there are multiple series:
>
> ```
>  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
>     ['Series Name 1', 'Series Name 2', 'Series Name 3', ...],
>     [series1_number1, series2_number1, series3_number1, ...],
>     [series1_number2, series2_number2, series3_number2, ...],
>     [series1_number3, series2_number3, series3_number3, ...],
>     ...
>   ]);
> ```

Having said that you  might want to convert the second column into number format:

```
var inputJson = [["val","b"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","5"],["val","1"],["val","12"],["val","7"],["val","11"],["val","1"],["val","7"],["val","6"],["val","16"],["val","11"],["val","21"],["val","12"],["val","1"],["val","22"],["val","16"],["val","1"],["val","21"],["val","11"],["val","6"],["val","11"],["val","15"],["val","12"],["val","12"]];
var chartJson = inputJson.map(function(item,i){
    if(i == 0)
       return item;
    else {
       return [item[0],parseInt(item[1])];
    }       
});

var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartJson);
```

Once the data is converted the chart will be rendered properly.

**Working example**

```js
google.load('visualization', '1.1', {
    'packages': ['corechart']
});
google.setOnLoadCallback(drawStuff);

function drawStuff() {
    
  

    var inputJson = [["val","b"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","3"],["val","5"],["val","1"],["val","12"],["val","7"],["val","11"],["val","1"],["val","7"],["val","6"],["val","16"],["val","11"],["val","21"],["val","12"],["val","1"],["val","22"],["val","16"],["val","1"],["val","21"],["val","11"],["val","6"],["val","11"],["val","15"],["val","12"],["val","12"]];
    var chartJson = inputJson.map(function(item,i){
        if(i == 0)
           return item;
        else {
           return [item[0],parseInt(item[1])];
        }       
    });
       
    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartJson);
    


    //The below input data works fine. 
    //var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([["val","d"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","2"],["val","1"],["val","2"]]);

    // Set chart options
    var options = {
        width: 400,
        height: 300,
        histogram: {
            bucketSize: 0.1
        }
    };

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.Histogram(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
};
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script src="chart.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```